# NameError: name 'config' is not defined

Tags: python, function, callback, nameerror

This error seems to have been asked earlier but I noticed the responses were to create a class and instantiate an object. Here I just define a function to read a yaml file and spit out the values.

```
    import yaml


    def read_yaml(file):
        with open(file, "r") as stream:
            try:
                config = yaml.load(stream)
                print(config)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
                print("\n")
        return config

    read_yaml(config.yaml)
    print(config)
```

This returns an error: " NameError: name 'config' is not defined ". I can print the data from yaml file but not the config returned by the function.

Comment: Change `read_yaml(config.yaml)` to `read_yaml("config.yaml")`.

Comment: Also, but maybe not related to the problem, your function is not returning any value.

Comment: Wow that did it! thanks a ton. I kept passing "file" in quotes in the function name & that obviously didn't work.

Comment: @pazitos10 - I am printing out the contents of the yaml so I didn't think to return anything else. What is a good convention to follow?

Comment: This returns an error: " NameError: name 'config' is not defined ". I can print the data from yaml file but not the config returned by the function.

Comment: Now you are trying to return a variable that's defined and assigned inside the `try` block, so outside of it, it doesn't exist. You can solve it defining config outside the `try` block (1st line of the function), and assigning it some initial value or returning two different things, config in the `try` block and the error message in the `except` block, as defined in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Comment: Never ever use `yaml.load()`. If you don't know why not, you don't need it (and then you should read the documentation).

Comment: Your function doesn't "spit out" anything, as the invocation of `print` is outside of the function.

Comment: Why is this tagged `callback`? You should read the tag descriptions instead of randomly applying tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to write:

```
read_yaml("config.yaml")
```

Remember that a string is delimited by two quotes.

Comment: Nice to know! So, verify my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the variable "config" inside the read_yaml function, but then you try to use the variable outside of the function (in fact, you're trying to pass it as an argument to the same function that defines it).

To solve the problem, change your last line to something like

read_yaml("file.txt")

Where file.txt is the name of the file containing your yaml.

Answer (score 0):

On the 4th line, you define the variable `config` (by assigning to it) *within the scope of the function definition* that started on line 1.  Then on line 11, outside the function (notice indentation), you try to access a variable named `config` in global scope (and refer to its attribute `yaml`) - but there isn't one.

Probably you didn't mean to access the variable on that last line.  Did you mean to pass the string `config.yaml` as the filename?  Then it needs to be in quotes.